# App Open Ads on admob - No ad config on test ads

Tags: admob, ads

We are trying to add a new format to our app. We used a test ad `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712`.
And in the `onAppOpenAdFailedToLoad` callback we get this

```
{
      "Code": 3,
      "Message": "No ad config.",
      "Domain": "com.google.android.gms.ads",
      "Cause": "null",
      "Response Info": {
        "Response ID": "null",
        "Mediation Adapter Class Name": "",
        "Adapter Responses": []
      }
    }
```

debug build.

What could be the problem?

Comment: You try to implement the new AppOpen Ad Format?

Answer (score 8):

I have changed the application id in the app .gradle file. (change the example to a different one)

```
 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.____._____"
}
```

Before running the app, delete the Build folder and uninstall the previously installed app.

Answer (score 2):

According to their doc, AdMob has new requirements [in order to receive test ads](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads):

**Option 1** (worked for us): Add this line to the `app-ads.txt` file for your app, and wait 24h for the AdMob crawler to update it:

```
google.com, pub-3940256099942544, DIRECT, f08c47fec0942fa0
```

**Option 2**: Enable test devices as explained here for [iOS](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/test-ads#enable_test_devices) and [Android](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads#enable_test_devices)

Answer (score 1):

- I also had this problem with test ads. I tried many solutions. But I didn't have success.
  And finally, this thing worked for me.

### What is the problem.

> while the application is under development. Then we set up testing ads. So due to frequent requests for ads, Google does not give ads to that package name.

### Solution.

> Change the application's package name, and ads will appear in your application.

##### Google Ads Test IDs

- Check out these Google Ads test IDs here.
  https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads#demo_ad_units

If ads still not showing then you can use below IDs.

| Ad Type | IDs |
| --- | --- |
| Banner Ad | /6499/example/banner |
| Interstitial Ad | /6499/example/interstitial |
| Native Ad | /6499/example/native |
| App-Open Ad | /6499/example/app-open |

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem.
Try to recreate RewardedAd object immediately before calling loadAd()
like this:

```
rewardedVideoAd = new RewardedAd(mActivity, ADMOB_UNIT_ID);
rewardedVideoAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build(), adLoadCallback);
```

Also make sure u did fresh install, and AndroidManifest contains your app id:

```
<meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
     android:value="ca-app-pub-0000000000~000000000"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I removed the ad unit id from the campaign I had associated it with.
The error was immediately gone.

Not sure why, but it seems using the same ad unit id for ad serving and campaign(s) might also cause this issue.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what causes the problem but testing on a physical device works for me.

Answer (score -1):

When you sure about your Android settings on your project, you have to check your Admob request counts whether you can successfully made a proper request or not.

[image]

So, according to the image above, go to Admob, choose your app, go to app overview page, and check your Request numbers probably ought to be different from zeros. If you can see only Zeros, you are making mistakes in your app. If it's different than zero, you have to wait your app must be get downloads from Google Play and users should stay in the app at least more than two minutes. Automatically every 30 seconds in a row, user will set a new ad request automatically, and probably they should make at least four requests by the app. Which means users are actively using your app and they might get an adview soon.

To sum up, wait new users to use your app and download from Google Play in the time.